# Configure testng.xml to run tests serially without typing each class

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am using selenium to automate some of the tests for a point-of-sales application. Because an external program is used to manage the communication between the application and external devices (printers, cash drawers...), only one browser session can be open at a time or the external program gets confused (ex: the cash drawer event for one browser session gets triggered in another).

I have currently been doing the following in my testng.xml file:

```
<suite name="Test Suite" verbose="10" preserve-order="True">
  <test name="Item Entry -- Quantity Required -- Basic" annotations="JDK">
    <parameter name = "filepath" value = "C:\Java Projects\Gravity\config\US\" />
    <classes>
      <class name="tests.itementry.quantityrequired.BasicPath"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
    <test name = "Item Entry -- Quantity Required -- Cancel">
        <classes>
            <class name = "tests.itementry.quantityrequired.Cancel" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

I previously tried specifying the package instead of the class, but that resulted in the tests running in parallel (multiple browsers opened at the same time). I know that another option is to combine the tests into one class (which may be the best design choice???), but I thought it would be best to make each scenario its own class.

Any advice on how to configure my testng.xml file or about turning test scenarios into testng tests would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Testng would by default run in sequence if nothing is specified in the parallel attribute of the suite.  Specifying the package should have solved your issue.  You can specifically define  parallel = false in your suite declaration and check why your tests are being invoked in parallel.   You can refer [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-tests) to see how. Check your code as well to see if teardown is not being done correctly.

From the dtd of the xml..

```
!ATTLIST suite
    name CDATA #REQUIRED
    junit (true | false) "false"
    verbose CDATA #IMPLIED
    parallel (false | methods | tests | classes | instances) "false"
```

And yes, defining all tests in one class is not a good idea.

Comment: I tried adding parallel="false", but it did not work. I'm going to try some logging to see if I can figure out at what point during the current classes' execution the new browser is opening. I'm using the @AfterClass annotation for my final method that closes the browser so maybe I've misunderstood its usage.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem. Used parallel="false" for both  and ; still multiple browsers are launched.
As a work around, I have annotated all my classes as @Test and assigned them a group name. Within this @Test annotation at the class you can define the order by using dependsOnGroups and set alwaysRun="true".
You can include the package and need to include all the groups in testNG xml.

```
<test name="My suite">   
 <groups>
    <dependencies>
      <group name="c" depends-on="a  b" />
      <group name="z" depends-on="c" />
    </dependencies>  
 </groups> 
</test>
```

Hope that works.